# How to call an id sender function from another function?

Tags: iphone, ios

In the following code example, I want to be able to call backgroundTap from another function btnSubmitLoginPassword. What parameter should I pass?

```
-(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id)sender{

    [userName resignFirstResponder];
    [password resignFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction) btnSubmitLoginPassword{

    [self backGroundTap:?????????]


    [self validate];


}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PengOne's answer is good, but the precise answer to your question is: pass `nil` for the sender parameter:

```
[self backgroundTap:nil];
```

Comment: +1: I did not answer the question, I worked around it. You answered it, and correctly.

Comment: I prefer using it this way, since it allows me to change it later much easier

Answer (score 5):

You aren't using `sender` in the action, so why not just leave it out?

```
-(IBAction) backgroundTap{
    [userName resignFirstResponder];
    [password resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction) btnSubmitLoginPassword{
    [self backGroundTap];
    [self validate];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are not using id value in the method

```
    -(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id)sender
   {

     [userName resignFirstResponder];
     [password resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

instead use like

```
  -(IBAction) backgroundTap
   {

     [userName resignFirstResponder];
     [password resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

and then make it call as

```
  -(IBAction) btnSubmitLoginPassword{

  [self backGroundTap];

   [self validate];
   }
```

if you want to change/access sender property alone then you should use (id)sender

Comment: Looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367468/how-to-call-an-id-sender-function-from-another-function/6367493#6367493

Answer (score 2):

Usually the sender parameter is UIView or any other object that generates the event. In this case it would be consequent to use self as a sender.